# Creating a pdf of react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf

I've for the last month trying to add my react component into a pdf without showing it on the screen, with no luck.

I've exhausted everything I could find on SOF, such as HTML2Canvas which can't be used in my case since the component have to be rendered before one can convert it to canvas and add it.

It does not have to be in the client.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the print media query in CSS?

You can do

```
@media print { 
/* Your CSS */
}
```

You can use this to hide a component with CSS on the normal page but then when it comes to printing you can make that component visible. The component will always need to be on the DOM though.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how that would work?

Comment: @MohammadSaad https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Comment: I'm not sure that works when we're going display:none -> display:block because the element can't be found in the first place. I think it only works the other way around.

Comment: @MohammadSaad I am not sure of the specific behavior of using display: none and switching to display: block in your print stylesheet. If doing that indeed doesn't work then you can always hide the element by displaying it absolute and then using off screen coordinates. However, i would say this is a 'hacky' solution.

If you want to be more elegant I would suggest using headless chrome as mentioned in other answers.

Comment: I think display:none removes it from the dom completely, and the same with position absolute. As for headless chrome, does it work without rendering the component?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to have users print your page to pdf using the print dialog, then GavinHenderson5's answer should be sufficient.  If you need to actually produce a PDF file that users can download, then a combination of GavinHenderson5's solution with something like [Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) may be preferable.

We have a backend endpoint setup that has a running Chrome instance that *then* calls a URL on the frontend (rendered React components) printing it to PDF.  Using print media queries, you can double dip any styling of the components or `display: none/block;` if you want to pick and choose for the rendering.

Comment: I'm trying to have a downloadable pdf, and as I mentioned in the other comment:

I'm not sure that works when we're going display:none -> display:block because the element can't be found in the first place. I think it only works the other way around.